# Histogram creation in lightgbm in the train API and the scikit-learn API. Is it always benefitial to use the train API?

Tags: xgboost, lightgbm, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

In the LightGBM for python we have a scikit-learn API in which (either for regression or for classification) there is [fit method](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html#lightgbm.train) whose documentation is

> fit(X, y, sample_weight=None, init_score=None, eval_set=None, eval_names=None, eval_sample_weight=None, eval_class_weight=None, eval_init_score=None, eval_metric=None, feature_name='auto', categorical_feature='auto', callbacks=None, init_model=None)

Where

> X : (numpy array, pandas DataFrame, H2O DataTable's Frame , scipy.sparse, list of lists of int or float of shape = [n_samples, n_features]) – Input feature matrix.

**So, this does not accept LightGBM's own dataset**

Now, for the [train API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html#lightgbm.train):

> lightgbm.train(params, train_set, num_boost_round=100, valid_sets=None, valid_names=None, feval=None, init_model=None, feature_name='auto', categorical_feature='auto', keep_training_booster=False, callbacks=None)

where the `train_set` is defined to be:

> train_set (Dataset) – Data to be trained on.

**This is LightGBMs native dataset**

LightGBMs dataset accepts a parameter called `max_bin` while creating it

I am not sure about it and it is not mentioned anywhere but If I am running the training on the same data with the same number of bins repeatedly (like while doing a hyperparameter search) then would I be creating the histograms every time in the case of the scikit-learn API and only once (while creating the dataset) in the case of the training API?